# What is mean by implementing a advanced job control framework to help chain multiple Map-Reduce jobs?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, oozie

I am quite new to Hadoop and I have currently been allocated a project on

**"Implement a advanced job control framework to help chain multiple Map-Reduce jobs i.e. investigate/improve upon existing org.apache.hadoop.mapred.jobcontrol package."**

This project is listed on Project Suggestion page under Random Ideas on http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ProjectSuggestions#research_projects

My confusion is, do I have to build an advance version of Oozie (which I think is a job control framework to chain multiple jobs) or something similar to that or does this means something completely different else.

What am I missing?

Comment: I am not sure. But then take a look at iterative map reduce, stratosphere and Mesos. This looks like combination of these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the project you are referring to might be related to [this Jira ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-215).

Right now the [JobControl class](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/jobcontrol/JobControl.java) is pretty bare, and it's missing a number of functionalities which could make a user's life easier. For example:

- Ability to get notifications when the job changes state: right now you just call `JobControl.run` and that's it, but in practice it could be interesting if I could get notified when something changes in my job.
- Re-submit failed jobs: you could implement a facility to resubmit a job when/if it fails, for example you could have a max number of retries parameter in the `ControlledJob` class and retry up to that point before  sending a notification that it failed.
- A lot of jobs are run on a regular basis, either weekly, daily, hourly, ... This is typically done via crontab, so it could be interesting to have this feature embedded in Hadoop, for example users could set a recurring job by specifying a period, and the JobControl would run it at these regular intervals.
- Maybe have a UI to visualize your jobflow and each job's dependencies, which steps have already been completed and whice haven't.
- It could be interesting to have the ability to not only launch Map/Reduce jobs, but also Hive, Pig for example, so you could provide a generic interface for users to submit any kind of job and monitore them seamlessly.

In the end I don't think you need to reinvent a completely new framework, the `JobControl` class already provides a good starting point. Try to think with the point of view of the user, what can you do to make it easier and shorter to submit and manage jobs. The ideas here and in the ticket are only example, you are free to come with your own ideas.

As far as **Oozie** is concerned, it gives you a higher abstraction for controlling a jobflow, but it's also more complex to setup and should be reserved for more complex jobs. I know for a fact that some people are hesitant to use Oozie because it adds overhead to your applications. The big difference also is that **Oozie** is a server while `JobControl` just runs on the client machine, which is additional overhead. While some of the features mentionned above are present in **Oozie** in 1 way or the other, the ability to keep it simple and running on the client machine without needing extra work like **Oozie** is in my opinion the key to your project.

Comment: Thank you for your reply charles, I am agree with you but the only doubt I have is - How is it different from Oozie. I think all the point you have mentioned is already present in Oozie framework?

Comment: @bril I added more details, in short yes some of the features are present in Oozie, but Oozie is a different animal which is much more complex and works as a server, I for instance am not using Oozie because it adds too much overhead and so I have utilities to help me manage these things on my client machine - which is what in my opinion you should try to do as part of your project by extending the already existing classes.

Comment: In that case Hamake http://code.google.com/p/hamake/wiki/HamakeComparisonWithOtherWorkflowEngines is a better alternative which runs on client side as utility and follow dataflow model and does almost all the work required. It again raises a confusion for me how to proceed my work.

Comment: @bril Hamake is a command-line utility if I'm not mistaken, you can't really control your jobflow directly through a Java API like `JobControl` which should be the whole point of your project. Also some features like notifications, retries or job scheduling are not supported by Hamake.